# Can I view the cin buffer for debugging purposes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, buffer, cin

I'm trying to debug a program that takes input from the console using cin.  Is there any whay that I can view the buffer while debugging?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean buffer incapsulated in cin, or buffer to what you going to get data via cin?

Comment: The input buffer that cin reads from.

Comment: if this a console app, the console buffer is responsible. I don't know if you can access that.

Answer (score 1):

You have the source to the STL, so you can step into the `cin` operations, doing this you'll eventually get into its internal stream buffer, in VS2010, there is the `_Mystrbuf` member, inside that is a pointer to the buffer you can view, `IGfirst`, take that address and paste that into a Memory window, as you do successive reads from `cin`, you can see these bytes start to fill up after the initial address.  For VS2008, these members might have different names.

**EDIT:** Eeek, I'm doing something wrong, I was getting all of the previously-entered data, now just the most recent.